# Might non-organic beings exist on an actual planet, as opposed to a moon?

Tags: aliens

In the past two years quite a few metallic objects have been observed leaving the dual planet system third from the Sun, such as that pictured here:

[image]

As is well known, the smaller of the dual planet system is completely solid and so could not support life. However, the larger of the pair does have 2/3 of its surface covered in liquid, and some scientists have supposed that simple life forms may be feasible there.

The objects observed leaving that system are inorganic, but they seem to be self-propelled and on specific trajectories to other solar-system objects. One even apparently orbited our host planet, then seemingly deliberately destroyed itself in the host planet's atmosphere. This leads to some scientists to draw conclusions:

- These objects are intelligent, as they seem to navigate the planets.
- These objects are immortal on their own world, as they seem to not fear the certain death of entering our host world's atmosphere.
- These objects may be a form of inorganic life.

**Based on the above, how likely is it that a life form, organic or inorganic, might live on an actual planet as opposed to on a moon as we do?** Might such an environment actually favor the non-organic beings that we have been observing? Might they really be immortal? If so, why have they only recently begun to leave their planet?

Additionally, it seems that spaceflight is achievable for us as well if we can find a place on our own home moon that has no water. **At least one object has been observed to leave that world not from the liquid part, but just a few hundred meters away on the dry part.** This might mean that one could leave a world by simply crawling out of the liquid and pushing on the planet. What other factors might complicate this? Could we do something similar someday?

**Edit:** In fact, I am asking the question from the point of view of intelligent beings in Europa's hypothetical ocean. I present the question as how they might perceive us. Our Earth-Moon system would appear to them as a binary planet, and the idea that life could develop on a planet, as opposed to a moon, would be strange for them. They might also suspect that the probes leaving Earth are the life forms on this planet. Of course, any being which evolved on Europa may suspect that life could only exist in an ocean.

Comment: Um, what are you trying ask?

Comment: While an entertaining PoV description - I don't see an actual question?

Comment: These observers who know they live on a moon (presumably Europa) and are able to record the origin a rocket launches from Earth to within a few hundred meters, but don't have any idea how that works? They have scientists, but no concept of machines? They call the Earth and Moon two planets, but then ask if life could possibly be on the planet and not a moon? This doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Maybe the question is being asked from the point of a species that lives on a Moon (to them which is a planet), and is confused about the satilites sent from Earth to explore other areas.

Comment: I have a feeling there's a really interesting question in here but it's still really vague. It would help if you removed the bold from the question the aliens are asking each other and then clearly stated the question you are asking and how what you have already written it doesn't cover it. (i.e. are you looking for more detail in a specific area?)

Comment: Try this. Keep the narrative. Add a `-----` under it, then phrase your question to us, from your point of view, plain and simple.

Comment: I think any creature able to build the scanning equipment neccesary to detect a probe, should be smart enough to figure out what a probe is and what built it.

Comment: They will not as Europe the Moon has a hidden ocean not external as per temperatures are -200 C plus and the ocean is  beneath tens of kilometers of ICE

Comment: @Erik, are you suggesting that Galileo was a rocket scientist?

Comment: I'm suggesting Galileo, where he able to see enough detail through his telescope to see a probe going through space, would probably immediately assume it was made by living creatures.